# Arma de doble filo

Tags: expresiones, diccionarios

Estoy buscando frases o expresiones equivalentes a 'Arma de doble filo' **en español**. No encontré nada acá y tampoco encuentro mucho en RAE o Wordreference, ni siquiera buscando la frase en inglés. Lo más cercano es "mixed blessing" pero no es exactamente el significado que busco, me interesa la característica de peligro asociada al arma. Agradezco sugerencias! Muchas gracias.

Comment: En español o en inglés?

Comment: En español, aunque quizás algo en inglés me "ilumine". Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las expresiones que se ocurren como similares a "arma de doble filo" son:

- salir el tiro por la culata (https://expresionesyrefranes.com/2007/01/23/le-ha-salido-el-tiro-por-la-culata/)
- búmeran / efecto búmeran (https://dle.rae.es/efecto#CmxMEAN)

Obviamente, de acuerdo con la oración, se usarán un tiempo verbal y una fraseología adecuados, ej:

- Lo que propones es un arma de doble filo.
- Con lo que propones te puede salir el tiro por la culata.
- Lo que propones puede ser un bumeran / puede tener efecto bumeran.

Todas las expresiones se refieren al uso de un arma que puede volverse en contra del que la utiliza.

Comment: Efecto búmeran me gusta y no se me había ocurrido, muchas gracias!

Comment: If the OP wants to search in English the phrase to look for is double-edged sword. I know the request was for phrases in Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

**Arma de doble filo**

La expresión "Arma de doble filo" del latín científico "distomos" y ésta de la palabra griega "δίστομος" (doble boca) que recoge la Biblia en Hebreos 4:12.

Hebreos 4:12

12 Porque la palabra de Dios es viva y eficaz, y más cortante que toda **espada de dos filos**; y penetra hasta partir el alma y el espíritu, las coyunturas y los tuétanos, y discierne los pensamientos y las intenciones del corazón.

Así la misma "palabra de Dios" puede ser un arma de dos filos, las metáforas y las mentiras en general también pueden serlo.

Cualquier decisión puede convertirse en algo contrario e inesperado a lo que se pretendía. Una ventaja podría convertirse en desventaja oculta con la que no habíamos contado o tenido en cuenta.

*Algunas de estas expresiones podrían sonar raro, ya que puede que sean localismos o regionalismos.*

- La belleza como arma de doble filo. La belleza utilizada como arma como seducción y manipulación para realizar una cosa que en principio no era la propuesta.
- Puerta doble.
- Puertas rotatorias de doble entrada. Que cambian las opiniones e ideas de personas por determinados intereses, produciendo esa ambigüedad contraproducente.
- "El Doble rasero" pueden hacer que las cosas proyectadas al fin nunca salgan como deberían o seria lo normal.
- Estoy "entre la espada y la pared". Una situación ambigua con peligro a ambos lados, y la toma de una decisión o cualquiera de ellas puede ser efectiva en un principio pero contraproducente al realizarla.
- Las "armas las carga el diablo". Puede que algo o una situación este bajo control, pero ésta puede descontrolarse o cambiar radicalmente en segundos, por tanto sería contraproducente realizar esa actividad por los riesgos inesperados que suelen entrañar.
- Doble sentido /Efecto contrario. Todas estas frases se refieren a una acción que puede tener no sólo el resultado buscado sino además uno inesperado.
- Doble llave (Se puede convertir en una... que abra cosas distintas a las que pensábamos)
- Doble arista (Tener aristas dobles). Hacen alusión a lo cortante de los dos extremos y a lo contraproducente que puede ser alguna de ellas en un momento dado.
- Es alguien que es "una bomba andante", es decir, que puede reaccionar en cualquier momento y dirección desconcertante.
- "Espada afilada por los dos extremos". (Se puede convertir en una...)
- "Espada de doble filo". (Se puede convertir en una...)
- "Hacha de doble filo". (Se puede convertir en un...)
- "Puñal de doble corte". (Se puede convertir en un...)
- "Espada de Damocles" (La decisión puede convertirse en una..., un peligro inminente), ("el arma de doble filo" puede convertirse en una espada de Damocles).
- "Lengua de doble filo" Las habladurías y rumores en un momento se pueden volver contra uno, obteniendo un resultado opuesto.
- "En la cuerda floja" El resultado puede bailar y caer en el lado contrario al esperado.
- Al final vas a conseguir "gato por liebre". Se dice de aquel que espera conseguir una cosa y obtiene otra.
- Puedes acabar "tirándote un tiro en el pie". Intentas llevar una acción en un sentido y al final puede que seas tu el que se perjudique.
- "Salir rana" Pensabas que era una cosa o de una forma y al final resulta que es de otra distinta.
- "Arma arrojadiza" Expresión que se puede utilizar contra sí mismo "Puede ser un arma arrojadiza contra si mismo" y convertirse en algo distinto y peligroso a lo que teníamos proyectado.

Comment: Caja de Pandora se me ocurrió con tu idea de la "Doble llave"; muchas gracias!

Comment: Gracias a ti por el comentario. Me alegro.